# What is better to certain values in a certain manner in C

Tags: c, optimization

I want to know which is the suitable way to store some generated values values? 
the values will be computed like so:

```
0
0  N/4   2N/4  3N/4
0  N/4²  ..    ..    ..    ..    (4²-1)N/4²
.
.
.
0  N/4^p ..    ..    ..    ..    (4^p-1)N/4^p
```

Is a table a suitable way? (I don't think so). A hashtable (how it will be accessed) or a structure??

Comment: How do you want to access the generated values?

Comment: Do you even need to store them ? From what I see you can always calculate them when asked if you are passed `N` and  `p`.

Comment: Suitable for what ? What are you _actually_ trying to achieve ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. There are literally [dozens of different data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures) that you could use for this purpose. The best choice depends on factors that you haven't explained here, including the size of your data set and the manner in which you intend to access it. As suggested by @SuperPeanut, your best option may be to not store this data at all. Please explain what you are doing if you want a sensible answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a table somewhat similar to a 2D matrix. However, to avoid wasting a lot of memory, I would make the rows of different length using dynamic memory allocation.

```
Row 0 : E                    // 1 element
Row 1 : EEEE                 // 4 elements
Row 2 : EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE     // 16 elements
Row 3 : EEEE..........EEEE   // 64 elements
and so on
```

Something like:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PMAX 4            // A total of 5 rows, i.e. p=0,1,2,3,4
double** table;

void init_table()
{
  int i;
  int j;
  table = malloc((1+PMAX)*sizeof(double*));  // Allocate number of rows
  for (i=0; i <= PMAX; i++)
  {
    unsigned int n = pow(4,i);               // Calculate number of elements needed
    table[i] = malloc(n*sizeof(double));     // Allocate the elements
    for (j=0; j < n; j++)
    {
      // calculate table values
      table[i][j] = i*100 + j;               // Replace with correct calculation
    }
  }
}

void free_table()
{
  int i;
  for (i=0; i <= PMAX; i++)
  {
    free(table[i]);
  }
  free(table);
}

double getValue(int p, int n)
{
  if ((p > PMAX) || (n >= pow(4, p))) 
  {
    // Some error handling here....
    // For now, just exit
    printf("Illegal use\n");
    free_table();
    exit(1);
  }
  return table[p][n];
}


int main()
{
  init_table();
  printf("%lf\n", getValue(0, 0));
  printf("%lf\n", getValue(1, 3));
  printf("%lf\n", getValue(3, 15));
  free_table();
  return 0;
}
```

In the code above I used the function `getValue` to read values so that I could check for illegal indexing. For performance that is kind of bad as it calls the `pow` function. So to get the best performance, you should skip the function and instead use `table[p][n]` directly. But then your algorithm must have some other way to ensure that indexing is legal.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what your constraints are.

If memory is a constraint but time isn't, then you can just write a function of n and p :

```
#define N 42
double function(double n, double p) {
    return (pow(4, p)-1)*N/pow(4,p);
}
```

Here your value would be :

```
value = function(n,p);
```

If time is a constraint but memory isn't, then you may prefer having a predefined table :

```
const double values_table[NMAX][PMAX] = {
{0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8},
{4, 16, 64, 256},
{..., ..., ..., ...},
};
```

Here your value would be :

```
value == values_table[n][p];
```

And you should consider creating this table with a script (python, Matlab, whatever you want) and copy-pasting it to your .c/.h file. For some simple calculation it could be done within a macro but as far as I know there is no way to compute x power y within a macro.

If none of the mentioned constraints matter to you then my preference goes to the function which is easier to read, maintain and use.

Comment: Why const N = 42 in first example ?

Comment: It's just an example value. I'm not sure to understand the formula in OP's table but I think N was a constant and wasn't dependent of the row or column, therefore I defined it before the function. If it's variable then it can simply be added to the function as a parameter, or to the table as a third dimension.

Comment: It's 4^p-1 not 4^(p-1)

Comment: @zoska Thanks I just fixed it. Actually the answer as well as the question should be more generic. A function is better if the time is less important than the memory footprint, and a table is better if the memory footprint is less important than the time. Short story of course, more complex problem will have a more complex answer but that's the idea.

Comment: A 2D array will waste a lot of memory. The first row shall only have 1 element, the next row shal have 4, the next 16 (4*4), the next 64 (4*4*4). The 11'th row 1048576 elements. A 2D matrix would use too much memory.

Comment: It all depends how many rows and columns the OP wants to have at his disposal. Anyway using a table was under the statement that memory is less of a constraint than time, and I can tell you that I've already met this situation often in embedded systems. Try doing a power, a multiplication and a division in a simple 8-bit microcontroller. Here a constant table is a better choice as long as its size is still in a reasonable range.

Comment: @TimF - you are missing my point. Tables can be real useful in many cases. My point is that a 2D array is the wrong table for this specific problem. If OP just need pmax to be 10, the table will require 1G x sizeof(double) of memory.  A pmax  of 11 would require 16G sizeof(double). That is not the way to do it.

Comment: @4386427 You're right, actually I did miss the fact that each row had a different size. Your solution is fine but on a system where mallocs are not recommended (e.g. embedded systems) this problem may have no elegant and efficient solution. I think a good macro could do the trick but I can't find any way to perform the power into a macro.